# The difference between 'What's new with that' and 'What's new in that'

Tags: word-usage

What's the difference between **what's new in that**, and **what's new with that**?

Here's an example of a conversation.

Person 1- Politicians are always shunning their responsibilities.
Person 2- What's new in/with that?

Are **In** and **with** interchangeable here?

Comment: You should add examples using both in actual usage, to confirm they are actually used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They seem to have two different meanings.

> What's new in that?

Meaning to say, "In what way is that news?"

> What's new with that?

Meaning to say, "What new information has been discovered relating to that?"

Another common thing to say, more common than both of those, is "What's new about that?"

[Here](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=What%27s+new+in+that%2CWhat%27s+new+with+that%2CWhat%27s+new+about+that&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CWhat%20%27s%20new%20in%20that%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CWhat%20%27s%20new%20about%20that%3B%2Cc0) is the google ngram result for the three.  Based on that, `"What's new with that?"` is very uncommon.  The ngram doesn't find any results for it.  I don't believe I've ever heard it.

[image: Ngram Screenshot]

Comment: I think adding *What's new about that* to the Ngram search will give us a better big picture.

Comment: @DamkerngT.: I have added that, but I can't figure out how to put the actual chart into the question.  Do you happen to know?  The HTML contained in the `Embed Chart` link doesn't seem to be showing up.

Comment: If it's possible, I do not know. I guess we have to make a screenshot ourselves. :(

Comment: @DamkerngT.: That's too bad, but it can be done.  It now has been done.